# Android-background change

Tags: android, button, background, drawable

So basically what I want to do is to change the background of the application when integer A value is greater than 50. I've tried using:

```
setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.imagename);
```

but it doesn't work.

I would really appreciate your help.

---

UPDATE:
    My code:

```
     package com.example.highhope;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.net.Uri;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
    import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
    import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
    import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.MenuItem;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.os.Build;

    public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {









        Button button;

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.fragment_main);

            addListenerOnButton();

        }

        public void addListenerOnButton() {

            button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

            button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {

runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.i0);
    }
});







                }

            });

        }

    }
```

My layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.highhope.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="90dp"
    android:text="Button" />
```

So for starters I'm just trying to change application background on button click and I've tried everything and nothing seems to work.

Comment: You need to provide some more details in order to get any useful answers. Elaborate on "it doesn't work" -- is it crashing? Or are you just not seeing the change take effect? Post some more code and your layout xml. It's possible that you're changing the background of the wrong view in your hierarchy.

Answer (score 1):

You can make that with a **Selector**, Check this [tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-imagebutton-selector-example/).

it's pretty easy, you just have to:

1. Add the images to your app resources
2. Create your background_button.xml (selector in the tutorial) in the drawable carpet
3. Set the background_button as your button background in your layout (`android:background="@drawable/background_button"`)
4. Set an onClickListener to your button
5. Test it!.

When you do it this way, the background of your button will change with no need of handle it programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

Are you making the background change in the UI thread? Try `setBackgroundResource` in the UI thread like below.

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bg);
    }
});
```

Also, if you are using a `Fragment`. you would have to put `getActivity().` in front of `runOnUiThread`.